# How to parse specific json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

Im using google api for generating places and maps. I have the json parsing code in php and i need it in javascript can someone help me with my code

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=pizza&sensor=false&key=MYKEY");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

  $var = $parsed_json->{'results'}[0]->{'formatted_address'};
?>
```

so with [0] im referring to the first result, how can do it in javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript supports JSON by default, there is no need to encode it.

```
$json = '{ "some": "valid", "json": "string" }';
$js = "var json_data = " . $json . ";";
echo $js;
```

This will print:

```
var json_data = { "some": "valid", "json": "string" };
```

---

If you don't have a JSON string - but a PHP array - you would use `json_encode`. Like so:

```
$json = '{ "some": "valid", "json": "string" }';
$json_data = json_decode($json); // now we have the JSON available in PHP mem
$js = "var json_data = " . json_encode($json_data) . ";";
echo $js;
```

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my question. I need the code in javascript to access json data in javascript.

Comment: JSON data from PHP right? Then PHP can print a script fragment to import the data to JavaScript (which is what my code does).

Comment: What i want to do is parse external json data like the one i mentioned from googleapi in javascript not in php. To read the json specific row for ex [0] but in javascript. I dont know if this is understandable. Thank you

Comment: Show us how you are calling this API in JavaScript then. I assume Google just has a whole library for you to use and you don't need to worry about JSON, you just get the data in JavaScript memory.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/a979d8540526825e/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {
  var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
  var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
  alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
  }
  });
});
</script> Here for example how can i alert specific row for example ['location'][0] this is not workin

Comment: This looks fine to me .. try `console.log(parsed_json)` and see what's in your console. This doesn't work so well in Internet Explorer. Firefox+FireBug or Chrome should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

All latest browsers supports parsing json natively. Usibg JSON.parse and JSON.stringify methods. For others use jquery builtin functions